# Cannot load tiles from Mapbox using leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I am a new user and I can't seem to get the tiles on the map.

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.512, -0.104], 1);

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/{mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8',
    accessToken: 'accessToken.here'
}).addTo(mymap);

var source = new EventSource('/topic/twitterdata2');

source.addEventListener('message', function(e){
    obj = JSON.parse(e.data);
    console.log(obj);
    lat = obj.place.bounding_box.coordinates[0][0][1]; 
    long = obj.place.bounding_box.coordinates[0][0][0];
    username = obj.user.name;
    tweet = obj.text;

    marker = L.marker([lat,long],).addTo(mymap).bindPopup('Username: <strong>' + username + '</strong><br>Tweet: <strong>' + tweet + '</strong>');

}, false);
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of whole layer name `{mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8}` you must specify just `{id}` in layer url. Also `id` value is wrong, it should be only `streets-v8`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code:

```
let yourMAP= L.tileLayer(
  "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=YourToken",
  {
    attribution:
      'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: "mapbox.streets",
    accessToken: "YourToken"
  }
).addTo(mymap);
```

And you need to get an access token on the Mapbox page. It is free for some number of requests, I am not sure how many, but should be enough for non-commecrial use. Then put the token in accessToken attribute or in the URL of the map(YourToken).
Check more at this page: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/mapbox-with-openlayers/